# telegram bot api бесконечно отправляет повторные запросы на сайт при долго выполнении кода

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте. Есть код в **index.php** на который приходят запросы от **телеграмм бота** (webhook  использую)

Сам **index.php**

```
$bot = new Telegram(TELEGRAM_TOKEN);
$message_id = $bot->sendMessage($bot->chat_id, 'start');
$message_id = json_decode($message_id, true);
$message_id = $message_id['result']['message_id'];

$a = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $result = "$i/";
    for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        $result2 =  $result . $j . '/';
        for ($k = 0; $k < 10; $k++) {
            $result3 =  $result2 . $k;
            $bot->editMessageText($bot->chat_id, $message_id, $result3);
        }
    }
}
$bot->editMessageText($bot->chat_id, $message_id, 'end');
```

**WebhookInfo**

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": {
        "url": "https://.../index.php",
        "has_custom_certificate": false,
        "pending_update_count": 3,
        "last_error_date": 1517492674,
        "last_error_message": "Read timeout expired",
        "max_connections": 40
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит метод **sendMessage()**

```
function sendMessage (string $chat_id, string $text):string
{
    $get = '/sendMessage?';
    $get .= 'chat_id='.$chat_id.'&';
    $get .= 'text='.urlencode($text).'&';
    $get .= 'parse_mode='.$this->settings['parse_mode'].'&';
    $get .= 'disable_web_page_preview='.$this->settings['disable_web_page_preview'].'&';
    $get .= 'disable_notification='.$this->settings['disable_notification'].'&';
    $get .= 'reply_markup='.$this->settings['reply_markup'];

    return $this->my_user($this->api.$get);
}
```

Вот так выглядит метод **editMessageText()**

```
function editMessageText (string $chat_id, int $message_id, string $text):string
{
    $get = '/editMessageText?';
    $get .= 'chat_id='.$chat_id.'&';
    $get .= 'message_id='.$message_id.'&';
    $get .= 'text='.urlencode($text).'&';
    $get .= 'parse_mode='.$this->settings['parse_mode'].'&';
    $get .= 'disable_web_page_preview='.$this->settings['disable_web_page_preview'].'&';
    $get .= 'reply_markup='.$this->settings['reply_markup'];

    return $this->my_user($this->api.$get);
}
```

Метод **my_user()** просто отправляет curl запрос телеграмму

Проблема заключается в том, что при отправке сообщения боту все запросы попадают в ожидание. Это можно пронаблюдать, если посмотреть на **WebhookInfo** а именно на **"pending_update_count"** оно увеличивается постоянно, при отправке новых сообщений боту. Если посмотреть на **"last_error_message"**, то увидим, что тайм-аут чтения истек (код на сайте не выполнился в течении 60 секунд). И телеграмм постоянно отправляет повторные запросы мне на сервер, ожидая ответа. В итоге получается бесконечно выполняющейся код, который ко всему еще и криво работает

[image: Read timeout expired]

На просторах stackoveflow нашел такую же проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950295/encountering-read-timeout-expired-error-by-webhook-after-60-sec-of-execution, но это не помогло

Как решить эту проблему? **Help me pls!!!**

И еще вопрос. Почему при отправке сообщений, все запросы от телеграмма на сервере становятся в очередь? Как сделать чтобы сразу выполнялись, без ожидания выполнения предыдущих запросов?

Comment: такая же проблема - цикл for больше 60 секунд и повторные запросы от апи телеги

Answer (score 3):

Понимаю, что уже не актуально, но для тех, кто найдёт этот топик. На любой запрос вашему боту от API телеграма нужно возвращать ответ с кодом 200, иначе сообщение считается не принятым и телеграм будет раз в минуту слать повторы.